# Is it necessary that an adult sit near a newborn baby in his carseat?

Tags: newborn, car-seat

I'm having twins. I installed two rear-faced car seats in my car. But there is no more place for me to sit near them.

Is it necessary that an adult sit near a newborn baby in his carseat to take care of him?

Comment: Would they only ever go somewhere with two adults so that one can drive and the other sit in the back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. If you would be more comfortable keeping an eye on them, there are mirrors you can install that allow you to see them in your rear view mirror. However, you will be wise to watch the road instead of the sleeping babies in the back seat; every newborn I've ever met just sleeps in the car so you won't be missing much.

Comment: If it's a long trip, plan on making regular stops.

Comment: Good point. Newborns are equipped with an alarm (crying) letting you know when it's break time, but you are right, a warning would have been nice!

Comment: If a newborn is likely to be spending a lot of time in a car seat then IIRC the primary concern is that it will affect their skull (as it is still soft.)  If I can find the specific info on that I'll post an answer.

Comment: @JamesSnell when my kids were babies (11 and 7 now) the recommendation was 2 hours max car seat time. And it was spine problems because of the curve in car seats.

Comment: @WendyG yes, car seats are no good for babies' spines or hips. Neither are those ridiculous infant carriers with the handles that click into a stroller and a car seat so you never have to touch, hold, or cuddle your baby, which also do all kinds of bad things to parents' shoulders and spines too. I wish I could remember the website I once visited that talked in depth about how bad these modern baby apparatuses are, but I can't. Do you happen to have a link?

Comment: No, it was just everywhere